# Recover files from formatted drive

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I have just installed a fresh copy of Windows as my previous version was corrupted. My drive C was formatted whereas my other drives are still there. I want to get some of my files back from my drive C. Is there any possible way to do this, such as with file recovery software like Remo Recover?

Comment: I used the trial version for Data Recovery Wizard Professional v3.3.4 and it restored ALL of my documents by doing a filter search for documents (.pdf,.doc, .xls etc) and I recommend it to everyone.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you, but you may not be that lucky again in the future. Maybe you learned a lesson about making sure you back up (or at least copy out) important data before formatting your drive. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well from their page I would say it is worth a shot, however it depends greatly on how the drive was formatted I would presume.

If a real format was completed then the drive was wiped completely. If a partial format was completed then the allocation table was wiped and there is a potential that Remo could find something.

At this point I would say you have a 50/50 shot.

Comment: No. Formats *never* wipe the drive. They just re-write the drive's "index". You need special tools to wipe a drive. The largest problem is data being overwritten by the install, not data being wiped.

Comment: @Bart: Quick formats just rewrite the MFT (drive's "index"). A full format will affect most sectors, although it doesn't overwrite every single one, which is why some (but seldom all) data can be recovered. See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting), in particular the second paragraph.

Comment: agreed, wiped is a bad choice of words.

Answer (score 1):

files that were not overwritten by your OS install MAY be recoverable. in this case look at [this document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) explaining TestDisk and Photorec. 
I usually use [Ubuntu Rescue Remix](http://www.ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/) for data recovery tasks, but there are many live CDs available with these two tools. PhotoRec is probably your best bet since you've already overwritten a good portion of your old partition.

Comment: I still have my Time Machine backups on an external drive, so nothing has been *lost* per se, I just want to log onto my now-restored system.